# Putty, Xming, Gedit, Windows 8 and Linux

Tags: linux, compilation, putty, gedit, xming

So I have Putty, Xming and Gedit installed on my Laptop (running Windows 8). I have accessed some files from my university by using putty so I can view the c files from Uni but how do I compile files I have saved in gedit/send the files to the university server or what not.

Basically I have a file/program/gedit thing saved to my laptop but how do I compile it if putty is connected to the university computers. 
Also I have gcc on my laptop I think.
As you can probably guess I am doing a computing course as an elective.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `psftp` which comes bundled usually with PuTTY? You can use that to transfer files to back to your university machine.

Alternatively you can use `pscp` which should also be bundled.

If you prefer GUI, try [Swish](http://www.swish-sftp.org/) which allows you to access your remote files via Windows Explorer.